# link to Ruby core class in YARD

Tags: ruby, yard

In YARD, when the parameter type or return type is a class in the same project, it automatically creates a link to the page of that class. Now I want to do the same to a Ruby core class (or any external class), says `Integer`. I want YARD to link any `Integer` type to http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Integer.html. Generally I want YARD to try to link

```
"http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/#{cls.name}.html"
```

if `cls` is not local to my project. Is that possible with YARD?

For guys familiar with Java, I am trying to do something like [the `-link` option of Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#CHDEDJFI).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's currently not possible, but the author has been considering. You can follow [this issue](https://github.com/lsegal/yard/issues/1121) for future updates. (I will also update this answer at that time.)

If I managed to spare enough time, maybe I would implement it myself.